# How to manage scroll per container in react native for web

Tags: react-native-web

For example I want the body element not to scroll
But one of its containing elements should be scrollable

I have used ScrollView and View element from react native but I don't get any scroll within my scroll view. I have switched off scroll on the body to isolate the scroll view to no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give flex:1 to the parent component of Scroll View .

For Ex:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
   <View>
      {whatever you want to scroll}
   </View>
</ScrollView>
</View>
```

Comment: These ideas didn't work on my test code. I have it working now without the wrapping <View style={{flex:1}}> or using contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}. Instead I set the ScrollView height to 100vh

Comment: 100vh works for web but not on phone. On the phone your solution works, but on the web that solutions does not provide the scroll management in my original question.